# Swift: Associating a transition with an animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

below are 2 code blocks of examples of applying transitions.  I am trying to understand how in the first code block below, the animation is associated with that `transition`?  What if there were other transitions in the code, then is that `easeInOut` duration applied to them all?  The 2nd example seems more clear cut since they are directly within the `transition` block:

1)

```
if show {
    LabelView()
        .transition(.opacity)
}

Spacer()

Button("Animate") {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
        self.show.toggle()
    }
}.padding(20)
```

and then it states: `Another option is to associate an animation with a transition. Note that the animation is applied to the transition, not to the view (i.e., it’s inside .transition()).`

with this example below:

2)

```
if show {
    LabelView()
        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
}

Spacer()

Button("Animate") {
    self.show.toggle()
}.padding(20)
```

Comment: What is your issue or question? can you explain?

Comment: @swiftPunk just differentiating between the 2 different options above ...is it that #2 is more specific and ties it to only 1 transition?

Comment: The use case number 2 seems too cool to be true! Unfortunately you cannot add animation like that to all kind of AnyTransition! seems just working with opacity and scale! The number one 1 is much completer than number 2, but number 1 lakes also lot's features than that you could get from `.animation()` view modifier.

Answer (score 0):

When you toggle `show`, SwiftUI knows that it will apply an animation of `.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)` to any changes, which happen as a result of mutating `show`.

In your first example, you have `LabelView`, which has an `.opacity` transition. When you add or remove it from the hierarchy with `if`, that opacity transition is used to fade it in and out.

In the second example, nothing that `show` changes will animate by default unless you explicitly specify an animation. In your case, `LabelView` will still animate because you *have* added that to the view.

> What if there were other transitions in the code, then is that `easeInOut` duration applied to them all?

Yes, it's applied to them all. Even though the value of `show` is technically changed instantly, the views will still animate.